# When I try to call SFINAE "createLog" function in C++ I get an Microsoft extension error

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm trying to call SFINAE `createLog` function, which is used to append argument to `log` and `message` parameters. Compiler always throws `use of member 'createLog' before its declaration is a Microsoft extension [-Werror,-Wmicrosoft-template]` error. I know that it is originally warn, but it is treated as an error, because of the `-Werror` parameter I use.

**The code I would use:**

```
template<typename ... Args>
static void RandomFunction(Args ... args) {
    std::string log;
    std::string message;
    
    createLog("random text", log, message); //all fine
    (createLog(std::forward<Args>(args), log, message), ...); //Compiler error "use of member 'createLog' before its declaration is a Microsoft extension [-Werror,-Wmicrosoft-template]"
}
```

**The "createLog" function declaration:**

```
template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string>> createLog(T &arg, std::string &log, std::string &message) {
    //I use std::string_view as container for ANSI escape codes
    if (std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, std::string_view>) {
        log.append(arg);
        return;
    }

    log.append(arg);
    message.append(arg);
}

template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>> createLog(T &arg, std::string &log, std::string &message) {
    log.append(std::to_string(arg));
    message.append(std::to_string(arg));
}

template<typename T>
static void createLog(...) {
    Warn("Type ", typeid(T).name(), " cannot be logged!");
}
```

I assume this error occurs, because the compiler doesn't know the types of template parameter pack, but I don't have any idea how to solve this. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention, that I'm getting another error.

**The another error:**

`no matching function for call to 'createLog'(createLog(std::forward<Args>(args), log, message), ...);`

Comment: I imagine you can solve this by moving the definition of `RandomFunction` below the definitions of `createLog`. So that all overloads of `createLog` are in fact defined before they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. After some testing I found out that the error is caused by `constexpr` values, so I added `std::decay`, which seems to solve my problem.

**The updated code:**

```
template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string_view>>
createLog(T && arg, std::string& log, std::string& message) {
    log.append(arg);
}

template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>>
createLog(T && arg, std::string& log, std::string& message) {
    log.append(arg);
    message.append(arg);
}

template<typename T>
static std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<std::decay_t<T>>>
createLog(T && arg, std::string& log, std::string& message) {
    log.append(std::to_string(arg));
    message.append(std::to_string(arg));
}
```